# Writing/Reading & Permissions

Tags: php, file-io, permissions, chmod, httpd.conf

Another dev and I are creating a website and we are using php to read/write to/from our site's directory. For some reason, everything on his end works fine but I can only get one type of I/O to work... If I modify my `httpd.conf` file and change the user:

```
User _www        //Change this to my system user name (Spencer)
Group _www
```

I can upload image files to our directory, but as soon as I make that change, I can no longer read text files which causes an exception:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

on this line:

```
var results = $.parseJSON(data);
```

If someone could help me better understand the relevant portion of the httpd.conf file I included above and help me with a direction for improving my setup, I would be very appreciative!

**EDIT:**

When I add a `console.log(data)` before the json parse, the output is `<b>Warning</b>:  chmod(): Operation not permitted in <b>/Users/Spencer/Programming/...` and the error contains the text of the file I'm trying to open..

After digging into it more, it turns out this is what is causing the problem: 
`chmod($fileName, 0777);`
and I guess that is a problem because the PHP user and the System user clash. I found some info about PHP and the `chmod()` function [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php)

*Removed irrelevant code*

Comment: so `console.log(data)` and see what got sent over. Probably you got some HTML instead of JSON. e.g. an http error page or whatever, which will probably contain a clue as to what the real problem is.

Comment: Great idea, let me add that and I'll comment the output.

Comment: Ok, so that's weird... the output is `<b>Warning</b>:  chmod(): Operation not permitted in <b>/Users/Spencer/Programming/...` which contains the text of the file I'm trying to open...